# UILocalNotification animates twice

Tags: ios, animation, ios9, uilocalnotification

I'm using the following code to schedule a `UILocalNotification` in my app. The problem is that the notification animates twice.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [UILocalNotification new];
localNotification.alertBody = @"Test message";
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

That code is executed in a button action. Then I send the app to the background and wait for the notification to be fired.

What happens is that I only have one notification but the animation (slide down animation) is executed twice.

First I was starting to think that it was an iOS bug, but then I created a very simple project with only the code that fires the notification and the problem did not happen.

When the app enters this state the problem occurs always. If I restart the device then everything starts working as expected. I did not manage to find the pattern that puts the app in this state.

This only happens on iOS 9 devices.

Comment: I recommend you find the pattern to reproduce this state, and then add the code for that. We can't help you with just this code.

Comment: Thanks @TroyT. The fcardoso response did help and I fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same exact problem a while ago and it was caused by multiple calls to `registerUserNotificationSettings` when initialising the notifications (in this case, in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`).

[This post helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047914/ios-push-notification-banner-shown-twice-for-a-single-push/33795327#33795327).